# Replace NaN in column with value from the same column when a second column matches

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas dataframe with NaNs in the "Value" column:

| Category | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Banana | **NaN** |
| Apple | 44 |
| Apple | 44 |
| Banana | 23 |
| Peach | **NaN** |
| Apple | **NaN** |
| Banana | **NaN** |

I want to fill those NaNs with the value of another row where "Category" column matches:

| Category | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Banana | **23** |
| Apple | 44 |
| Apple | 44 |
| Banana | 23 |
| Peach | **NaN** |
| Apple | **44** |
| Banana | **23** |

The "Category" column can have duplicate values and is not sorted, but the same category will have the same non NaN value (ie. Apple is always 44, Banana is always 23). Also, there may not be any non-NaN entries for a row, so the row should stay as NaN ("Peach" example above).

Sorting on category and using `df.fillna(method='ffill')` sort of does what I want, but does not work when there is not another matching row category and will fill rows with the wrong value.

Comment: `df['Value'] = df.groupby('Category')['Value'].transform('first')`